# Is it possible to upload a certificate .p12 file using REST API or any other type of connection?

Tags: rest, parsing, parse-platform

I'm looking for a way to upload certificate .p12 files for apps to parse.com using REST API or any other type.
Couldn't find an answer in parse.com docs.
Thanks,
Liran.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to use any API to upload your Push certificates. This can only be done via the dashboard.

Comment: Are there any plans to support such a feature?

Comment: I do not know as I am not a Parse engineer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Parse are closing this service which makes the whole process obsolete. Thanks.